# What color model does WebP implement?

Tags: image, format, webp, srgb

Does it natively support sRGB? When you load and save image data using the `libwebp` API, do you assume linear or sRGB encoded data? Is there a way to indicate you'd like sRGB data?

Does it natively support associated alpha? When you load and save image data using the `libwepb` API, do you assume unassociated or associated alpha? e.g. if I have a pixel buffer containing associated alpha, do I need to convert it to unassociated alpha before saving with `libwebp`?

Comment: sRGB is a color-profile, and you can include ICC into webp. [The default is assumed to be sRGB](https://developers.google.com/speed/webp/docs/riff_container#color_profile) though.

Comment: Thanks, yes I'm aware of that. I noticed in `decode.h` that there are constants (in `WEBP_CSP_MODE`) for both associated and unassociated alpha. I'm digging through the source code right now to try and find out the answers I need.